# Let $f:A\rightarrow B$. Prove that if $ X\subseteq A$, and $f$ is one to one, then $f(A)-f(X) \subseteq f(A-X)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $f:A\rightarrow B$. Prove that if $ X\subseteq A$, and $f$ is one to one, then $f(A)-f(X) \subseteq f(A-X)$.

Could anyone please guide me through this problem? I got stuck and don't know if what I'm doing is right. Thanks.

Comment: Why is this discrete mathematics?

Comment: @Gustavo: Because the basic facts about relations and functions are frequently taught in elementary discrete math courses. If that’s where the OP encountered it, it would be natural to apply that tag.

Comment: Oh I see. I saw those things in a Pre-Calculus course, not in Discrete mathematics.

Comment: Fwiw, I'll mention that we actually have $f(A)\setminus f(X)=f(A\setminus X)$ here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My attempt: assume that $y\in f(A)-f(X)$. Then $y\in f(A)$, $y\not\in f(X)$. Since $f$ is surjective over $f(A)$ and injective by definition, there exists only one $x\in A$ such that $f(x)=y$. Now, if $x\in X$, $f(x)=y\in f(X)$ which is false. Therefore $x\not\in X$, that is, $x\in A-X$ and thus $f(x)\in f(A-X)$. This shows that $f(A)-f(X)\subset f(A-X)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f:A\rightarrow B$. Prove that if $ X\subseteq A$, and $f$ is one to one, then $f(A)-f(X) \subseteq f(A-X)$.

My attempt:

Definition : $f(X)$= { $y\in B | y=f(x), \exists x\in X $ }

Let $y\in f(A)-f(X)$ | NTS : $ y\in f(A-X)$

$y\in f(A)$ and $y\notin f(X)$

Here is where I'm not sure if I took the right approach;

$\exists x\in A $ such that $y=f(x)$

but since $y\notin f(X)$ , then $ x \notin X$

Thus $x\in A-X$

Therefore $ y\in f(A-X)$

Comment: One suggestion: use less symbols and more text. I'm having a hard time to understand what you did. What did you mean by $f(X)=y$?

Comment: @GustavoMarra, are you referring to the line with the [definition](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/0/0/b/00bf47e271159edbefbd56b3c5b81bd0.png) of $f(X)$ ?

Comment: Yes, I see you corrected it. There's also another correction to be made, right after the part you say that you're not sure if you took the right approach; $\exists x\in A$ and not in $X$.

Comment: What is line 4 saying? What is NTS? Also, order matters: In line 3, what you want to say is "$\exists x\in X, y=f(x)$" rather than the other way around.

Comment: I guess "NTS" is "Note to self" as in "this is what I want to prove"

Comment: Perhaps. In that case, it would be better to write "This is what I want to prove", so people other than the author can actually understand (and make suggestions). For example: Remove the $|$ in that line, as it is distracting and serves no purpose. (I see that, and think, did they forget some {}? Are they defining a set?)

Comment: I don't know, some parts are confusing. In my first comment I suggested more text and less symbols.

Comment: @Gustavo: NTS is *Need To Show*.

Comment: I stand corrected :-)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, Thanks for making the abbreviation clear.

Comment: @Gustavo, Thanks for pointing out those two mistakes, I see in my notes that I made wrote X instead of A. Now if I replace my $y$ in my solution for the $f(x)$ as you did, I will get your answer.  :)

Answer (score 3):

This is actually an extended comment on your attempt to answer your question. First, I agree completely with Gustavo’s advice to use more words and fewer symbols. A proof must first of all be correct, of course, but after that your main goal should be clarity; typically this means using enough words to make the flow of the argument clear to the reader. Thus, the first two lines of your argument would be clearer if written out like this:

> Let $y\in f[A]\setminus f[X]$; we want to show that $y\in f[A\setminus X]$, and we know that $y\in f[A]$ and $y\notin f[X]$.

Your next two lines are contradictory: on the one hand you assert that there is an $x\in X$ with a certain property, and on the other you say that this $x$ cannot be in $X$. I think that you have the right basic idea in mind, but you’ve not expressed it very clearly. I think that this is what you’re trying to convey:

> Since $y\in f[A]$, there is an $x\in X$ such that $y=f(x)$. But $y\notin f[X]$, so $x$ cannot belong to $X$, and therefore $x\in A\setminus X$. Thus, $y=f(x)\in f[A\setminus X]$, as desired.

**Added:** I see that while I was writing this, you corrected the problem; what you have now is much better, though it could still benefit from more verbal ‘connective tissue’. Your proof is now correct.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Brian. I would try to keep it in mind for future proves.

Comment: @Kururugi: You’re welcome.